# Æ Ø Å characters in Rails seed file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im seeding data to my rails app. The content Im seeding has special characters Æ Ø Å (UTF-8).
However rails throws an error:

```
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
```

How do I handle special characters in seeds.rb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay here is the solution:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

This should be entered as the very first line of the seeds.rb file

Comment: Actually you can omit ruby and just enter `# encoding: utf-8`. Starting with Ruby 2.0, UTF-8 is assumed by default so you can omit the encoding declaration all together.